# Nextjs 14 event listener doesn't work inside template.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, mouseevent, next.js13

I have a layout.js and a **template.js**, to manage page transition effects inside the template.

my code inside **template.js** is:

```
'use client'

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export default function Template({ children }) {
    const [mousePosition, setMousePosition] = useState(null);
    const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        const updateMousePosition = ev => {
            setMousePosition(ev.clientY)
            console.log(ev.clientY)
        }
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', updateMousePosition)
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('mousemove', updateMousePosition)
        }
    }, [])

    // MOBILE DETECT
    useEffect(() => {
        function handleResize() {
            setIsMobile(window.innerWidth < 768);
        }
        handleResize();
        window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize, {passive:true});
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
        }
    }, [])

    return (<>
        {isMobile != null &&
            <main
                style={ isMobile ? {marginTop:`${mousePosition}px`} : {} }
            >
                {children}
            </main>
        } 
    </>)
}
```

why `mousePosition` doesn't get logged in the console as i move the mouse up and down the screen?

Comment: Did you pass the children inside the Template component? Some logic needs to be fixed, for example, mousePosition, isMobile, isMobile check and set up.